# Rickshaw: slider not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, time-series, rickshaw

I'm trying to get a decent understanding of rickshaw so I've been trying to add functionality to one of the simpler examples, but the range slider just isn't working. I've been looking at the code for this example to try to get it to work, but even though my code looks the same it just isn't working. Part of my problem is that I'm not sure what all the minified files contain, so I'm not sure when I need to include individual .js files for which functionality. As I'm sure you've noticed the documentation doesn't cover this,

so if any of you have any insight for me it would be greatly appreciated.

A note about the below code, I'm using jinja2 templates, thus the url_for functions

```
vvv This is the rendered code for the pertinent section of html vvv
<div id="preview" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget content ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 100%;"></a>
</div>
-------------------------------------------------
<!doctype>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" source="http://jqueryui.com/slider/">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='src/css/graph.css')}}">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='src/css/detail.css')}}">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='src/css/legend.css')}}">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='src/css/lines.css')}}">

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/d3.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/d3.layout.min.js')}}"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='rickshaw.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='extensions.js')}}"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.Preview.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chart_container">
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="legend_container">
        <div id="smoother" title="Smoothing"></div>
        <div id="legend"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>

<script>

// set up our data series with 50 random data points

var seriesData = [ [], [], [] ];
var random = new Rickshaw.Fixtures.RandomData(150);

for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    random.addData(seriesData);
}

// instantiate our graph!

var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.getElementById("chart"),
    width: 960,
    height: 500,
    renderer: 'line',
    stroke:true,
    preserve:true,
    series: [
        {
            color: "#c05020",
            data: seriesData[0],
            name: 'New York'
        }, {
            color: "#30c020",
            data: seriesData[1],
            name: 'London'
        }, {
            color: "#6060c0",
            data: seriesData[2],
            name: 'Tokyo'
        }
    ]
} );

graph.render();
var slider = new Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider({
    graph: graph,
    element: document.getElementById('slider'),
}); 
var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail( {
    graph: graph
} );
var legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend( {
    graph: graph,
    element: document.getElementById('legend')

} ); 
var shelving = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle( {
    graph: graph,
    legend: legend
} );  
var order = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Order( {
    graph: graph,
    legend: legend
} );
var highlight = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Highlight( {
    graph: graph,
    legend: legend
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see that you have jQuery UI included, yet it does not seem to be used. What specifically is not working? It may also be better to include the rendered HTML versus templates. Also do you see any errors in your browsers console?

Comment: The program uses jQuery UI to actually render the slider, it's linked to at the top of the file. I'll add the relevant rendered html. There are no errors in the browser console, and all the other elements are rendered, it's just the slider that is not rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Using the demo here: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/ and the standalone example: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html it only needs the `id` of the `div` to initialize.

I would advise removing the following from your `head`:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" source="http://jqueryui.com/slider/">
```

And using:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" source="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.csss">
```

I don't think this will cause an issue but it also does not improve anything.

I also see they use:

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

They execute this before the jQuery UI is included. I see no issue with:

```
var slider = new Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider({
    graph: graph,
    element: document.getElementById('slider'),
});
```

If it were me, I would suggests:

```
// set up our data series with 50 random data points
var seriesData = [
  [],
  [],
  []
];
var random = new Rickshaw.Fixtures.RandomData(150);
var graph, slider, hoverDetail, legend, shelving, order, highlight;

for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
  random.addData(seriesData);
}

// instantiate our graph!
graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
  element: document.getElementById("chart"),
  width: 960,
  height: 500,
  renderer: 'line',
  stroke: true,
  preserve: true,
  series: [{
    color: "#c05020",
    data: seriesData[0],
    name: 'New York'
  }, {
    color: "#30c020",
    data: seriesData[1],
    name: 'London'
  }, {
    color: "#6060c0",
    data: seriesData[2],
    name: 'Tokyo'
  }]
});

graph.render();
slider = new Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider({
  graph: graph,
  element: $("#slider")[0]
});
hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
  graph: graph
});
legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend({
  graph: graph,
  element: $("#legend")[0]

});
shelving = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle({
  graph: graph,
  legend: legend
});
order = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Order({
  graph: graph,
  legend: legend
});
highlight = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Highlight({
  graph: graph,
  legend: legend
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qoofL8kb/4/

Comment: changing it from `element: document.getElementById('slider'),` to `element: jQuery('#slider'),` made it so the legend didn't render either, the other changes you suggested had no effect.

Comment: I am unable to replicate your issue. Took a bit of work, but I have created the following fiddle to test in: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qoofL8kb/

Comment: I suspect your issue is the CSS for jQuery UI. I would change that first call from `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" source="http://jqueryui.com/slider/">` to `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" source="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">` this should allow the slider to render properly.

Comment: @theMudkip it looks like it does not like jQuery Objects for the `element` attribute, so you can use `$("#slider")[0]` and `$("legend")[0`] to easily pass the element. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qoofL8kb/3/

Comment: I made the changes you suggested again and it's still missing that one piece. Could it be related to the fact that I'm using templates? I wasn't sure if this was relevant but I'm also using flask, though that shouldn't have any effect on this. Thank you

Comment: @theMudkip as long as they appear properly to the browser, they should load. jQuery UI relies on the CSS to render the Slider. You mentioned that no errors were generated, so that would suggest all the includes are in their proper place and can be read. You can test by loading them directly in your browser. Review the Source of your resulting HTML and make sure nothing is creating an improper path, relative or absolute.

Comment: There were some hidden characters in the link I was trying to use, and even when I removed them it didn't render properly so I figured the URL was out of date (or something along those lines) so I downloaded the package and included the css from there

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with it I realized the problem was the way I was trying to link to the jQuery-ui css file. Instead I downloaded the files I needed and added them to the project, linking them that way.